# Strange messages on new Dell Workstation during bootup

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed Windows 7 Ultimate on a new Dell T-7500 Workstation, and am seeing some strange messages on the screen:

**Dell SAS 6 Host Bus Adapter BIOS
MPTBIOS 6.22.03.00 ( 2008.08.06 )
Initializing…..
Press Ctrl – C to run SAS Configuration Utility
Searching for Devices at HBA 0…..
Dell MPT Boot ROM Successfully installed**

Then it loads Windows 7.

All of above happens on its own, I don't touch anything.

So what is going on & what do I have to do get rid off those initializing commands ? I have never had this happen to any previously owned Dell systems.

Also I haven't installed any drivers yet but Sound, Video & Internet does work. Do I need to install any additional drivers?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your computer. Those lines you see is the initialisation of the RAID controller and can be ignored.

As for the drivers you need to install, go into Device Manager and check which devices are not installed yet. Then visit the Dell website, and using your computer model, look up the appropriate drivers to download and install that matches the uninstalled devices (if any).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it has a [seperate SAS card](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/pvaul/topics/en/us/raid_controller?c=us&l=en&cs=555), and it has its own bios, that initialises before the OS starts. This is normal for pretty much any HBA card. If you arn't using raid, and just using a standard SATA drive connected to the motherboard directly, removing the card may be an option - i did this with a system that had an old SCSI card which took ages to initialize.