Wierd bios text

The image is my screen after I configure the bios,I hit F10 to save and then see this.
It reads

Intel(r)Eaglelake PCI Accelerated SVGA BIOS
Build Number: 1718 PC 14.34 12/01/2008 22:45:30
DECOMPILATION OR DISASSEMBLY PROHIBITED
Copyright (C) 2000-2003 Intel Corp. All Rights Reserved.

I wonder what is this screen/text, can anyone explain?

See also https://superuser.com/q/404211/ for an example of another bios screen, this time for storage .

While modern systems hide that and other fun stuff, your GPU, addon storage cards, and network cards do have their own Bios/firmware, and on older machines these would initialise before the main bios and have their own loading screens. If you configured your bios, your system completely reinitialises.
A quick google suggests Eagle Lake is a core 2 duo era chipset. Pre Ivy Bridge processors didn't have on die/package GPUs so the 'integrated' GPU on these machines was a additional chip sharing the PCI lanes with your discrete GPU (so it was one or another), and these adaptors would boot before your main system so you had graphics output.
With a modern system, UEFI firmware rather than bios, quickboot and such you're less likely to see these but with these older systems this and other things were normal.


BIOS product name
BIOS version
Notice about acceptable usage
Copyright notice

